# Aws device farm execution with jenkins having parametarization

Tags: java, jenkins, testng, appium, aws-device-farm

I want to setup environment, device name and suite as a parameter from Jenkins and that should be run on device farm. I already created parameters on Jenkins job but it is not taking it. Could you please help me to understand the script configuration setup part. I am using java TestNG appium project Maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the parameters, you pass them through to the Device Farm from within the script. For example, if you configured `ANDROID_DEVICE` to be the device name and `ANDROID_SUITE` to be the suite name, then in your pipeline script you would configure it like so:

```
# Include your parametrized values at the top of the pipeline scrip
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'ANDROID_DEVICE', defaultValue: 'Google Pixel 4', description: 'Device to test.', )
   ])
])
```

```
# When making the call to Device Farm from within the script, reference these values
  stages {
    stage('Run Device Farm Test') {
      steps {
          devicefarm (
            devicePoolName: ${params.ANDROID_DEVICE},
            .
            .
            .
            )
```

If you need additional assistance, I suggest reading the [Jenkins Plugin Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/continuous-integration-jenkins-plugin.html) from device farm or this great article on [parametrized values in Jenkins pipelines](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines). If you still require assistance, I suggest moving to the [AWS Device Farm forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193) for assistance from their engineering team.